Can Angular Storybook Providers Dynamically Set Default Language Based on Query String?
I'm utilizing the Storybook-i18n library for internationalization support within Storybook.
Upon changing the language, it also reflects in the URL, like so: locale:en
http://localhost:4400/?path=/story/foocomponent--primary&globals=locale:en
Now, I aim to integrate this functionality into the providers I'm passing to Angular Storybook:
const meta: Meta<FooComponent> = {
  component: FooComponent,
  title: 'FooComponent',
  decorators: [
    applicationConfig({
      providers: [
        provideI18N({
          config: { availableLangs: ['en', 'fr'], defaultLang: 'en' }, //<-- defaultLang should be determined dynamically from the querystring locale: ??
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

export default meta;

I've explored the Storybook docs, but it doesn't seem to align with my needs as it suggests using a render function which I prefer not to introduce here.
Hence, I'm wondering if it's feasible to access the globals using the import {} statement or read them directly from the querystring.
